# How to retrieve values within an array

Tags: ruby

```
  def self.foo
    [
      ["a","aa"],
      ["b","bb"],
    ]
  end
```

Given "a", I should be able to retrieve "aa"
Given "bb", I should be able to retrieve "b"

How do I do this?

Comment: What prevents from making a normal hash out of this?

Comment: This datastructure is called a *bi-directional map*, *bidimap*, *bimap*. Maybe you can find a Ruby implementation somewhere, but it doesn't look good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[assoc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-assoc) and [rassoc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-rassoc) are your friends:

```ruby
ar = [
  ["a","aa"],
  ["b","bb"],
]
p ar.assoc("a").last #=> "aa"
p ar.rassoc("bb").first #=> "b"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Hash[self.foo].invert["bb"] #=> "b"
Hash[self.foo]["a"] #=> "aa"
```

`Hash[]` turns array into hash

`Hash#invert` inverts the hash so all values map to the keys

If you want to do both:

```
Hash[self.foo]["bb"] or Hash[self.foo].invert["bb"] #=> "b"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create my own "bimap" implementation, perhaps something like:

```
class Bimap < Hash
  alias :__put__ :[]=
  def []=(key,value)
    __put__(key,value)
    __put__(value,key)
  end

  alias :__size__ :size
  def size
    __size__ / 2
  end

  # ...any other Hash methods to reimplement?
end
```